# How can I get the text from a component in a JList?

Tags: java, string, swing, jlist

I have a `JList` and I am wanting to get the text of an entry of that list at a specific index. Could someone inform me how to do this or should I restructure my code to `getValues` instead of `getIndices`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
JList dataList=(...)

 for(int i = 0; i < dataList.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
     System.out.println(dataList.getModel().getElementAt(i));
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Object[] temp = jList1.getSelectedValues();
temp[i] = the object you want.
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want? That only works if all objects in the list are selected.

Comment: I only need to get the objects of the items that are selected, I probably forgot to say that sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
DefaultListModel list = new DefaultListModel();
JList jl = new JList(list);

int i = 21;
Object = element;
String = yourElement;

element = jl.getModel().getElementAt(i);
yourElement = element.toString;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String nick = jListNicknames.getModel().getElementAt(index).toString();
System.out.println(nick);
```